# jQuery Mobile - Extra icon in collapsible header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to add an extra icon from fontawesome to the right of a collapsible header in jQuery Mobile, apart from the default one to the left. Sorta like this:

[image: What I want to achieve]

To the left of Madrid would be the default icon, and to the right the star icon and number, like a rating. Anyone knows how to do this?

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h3>Madrid encantado<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the part of the code that forms the header. The text inside the h3 defines the title and content of the header, but trying to put the icon inside does not work.

Comment: Can you share what you already have?

Comment: I edited the question and added it

Comment: So basically you want to add an icon before (on the left) Madrid ?

Comment: The photo is a mockup. There is already an icon by default to the left, that says if the tab is opened or closed. I want to add the ratings icon to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question, this is what you want

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui-collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i> Madrid encantado <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is it, it is working now, I don't know what happened before